# Why can structs not be defined in a function declaration in C++11 or higher?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

What I am trying to achieve is mainly returning an unnamed struct from a function in C++11. In C++14, I can do this by defining the function inline and having `auto` as return type, like this:

```
auto func()
{
    struct
    {
        int member;
    } ret;

    // set ret.member

    return ret;
}
```

However, C++11 doesn't support deducing the return type of a normal (non-lambda) function, and this only works in C++14 when the definition is done inline.

I tried the following two variations of declaring the struct in the function declaration:

```
auto func() -> struct { int member; };
struct { int member; } func();
```

Is this simply impossible to do with C++11? If so, does someone know whether this was disallowed on purpose or just nobody thought of this new use of automatically deduced types (because this only works with the functions return value being assigned to an `auto` variable)?

And finally, is there any other way to achieve something similar to this? I am aware of `std::tuple`, but I want to name the values; and in my use case the struct type is definitely only useful as return type of this one function, so why name it?

Comment: It was not disallowed on purpose; it simply had not been designed yet, and the committee was wary of doing too much specification around `auto` without real world experience. Remember the fiascos of `throw` specifications or extern templates. And remember that the C++11 were to be released well before 2009 so they were already quite late.

Comment: C++11 and 14 are considered more of a package deal. The latter being the completion of the former in many ways. So it's more a case of the functionality you want not making it into the first 'half' of the rollout.

Comment: Is it disallowed in the specification though, or should `struct { int member; }` be a valid return type for a function (generally, not only in C++11 and higher), and compiler developers just didn't think of this possibility (as it was useless before C++11)?

Comment: unnamed structs are allowed in the standard (which is what you have) so as far as I know, it should be allowed. The only reason you couldnt return it previously is because there was no deduced return type. I dont think you can do exactly what you want without a C++14 compliant compiler.

Comment: qeadz: Yes of course unnamed structs are principally allowed. The two declarations of the second code block in my questions don't work though, otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question. They are both rejected by g++ 4.9.2 and clang 3.5.1, no matter whether I use `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[dcl.fct]/p11:

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types.

This is not new in C++11, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

A *class-specifier* consists of a *class-head-name* and `{ }`. Once the closing brace is encountered, the class is defined. If the *class-head-name* is omitted, the class is unnamed (§9). A *type-specifier* can have a *class-specifier*, but *trailing-type-specifier* can't (only *simple-type-specifier*, *elaborated-type-specifier*, *typename-specifier* and *cv-qualifier* are allowed, §7.1.6). For this reason, I believe that it's not possible to put the definition of a class in a *trailing-return-type*.

Source: N4140

Comment: I couldn't find the N4140 document, only one reference to N4296 which seems to be a revised version of the same document (fourth document [here](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/cpp-proposals-by-mailing-and-subgroup-for-2014.html#mailing2014-11-)). Could you have a look at that and point out where the relevant things are defined?

Comment: @jP_wanN Download it from [github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf)